# Checking correct brackets question in java

Tags: java, algorithm, brackets

An input string is valid if:

- Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
- Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Note that an empty string is also considered valid.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        int len = s.length();
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            char cur = s.charAt(i);
            if(cur=='{'){
                stack.push('{');
            }
            else if(cur=='['){
                stack.push('[');
            }
            else if(cur =='('){
                stack.push('(');
            }
            else if(stack.peek()=='(' && cur==')'){
                System.out.println(stack.peek());
                stack.pop();
            }
            else if(stack.peek()=='[' && cur==']'){
                stack.pop();
            }
            else if(stack.peek()=='{' && cur=='}'){
                stack.pop();
            }

        }

        if(stack.empty()) return true;
        else return false;

    }

}
```

When I give the input as:

```
")"
```

I get an error:

```
java.util.EmptyStackException
```

in the line where I check the condition for `')'`. Please explain

Comment: You need to debug mate. That's how you can improve your logic

Comment: Yea ... I see the problem.  Hint: what actually happens if the first character of the input is `)` ? Read the code carefully.  (Try "rubber duck debugging" ....)

Comment: Because for this case your stack is empty and you try to pop something out of it.  There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62236025/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-a-java-code-for-detecting-valid-parentheses-in-a/62237476#62237476) not so long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're solving [LeetCode 20](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/), which you can simplify your code a bit. For example, `return stack.isEmpty();` would suffice for your `return` statement.

Here are more readable versions:

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String baseString) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (char character : baseString.toCharArray()) {
            if (character == '(')
                stack.push(')');

            else if (character == '{')
                stack.push('}');

            else if (character == '[')
                stack.push(']');

            else if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != character)
                return false;

        }

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

#### C++

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String baseString) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (char character : baseString.toCharArray()) {
            if (character == '(')
                stack.push(')');

            else if (character == '{')
                stack.push('}');

            else if (character == '[')
                stack.push(']');

            else if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != character)
                return false;

        }

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, base_string):
        memo = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']': '['}
        stack = [0]
        for character in base_string:
            if character in memo:
                if stack.pop() != memo[character]:
                    return False
            else:
                stack.append(character)
        return stack == [0]
```

#### Reference

[Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/solution/)